# Check whether two objects of interface are equal (without overriding)

Tags: java, object, if-statement, interface, equals

I have an interface :

```
interface Query
{
    Set<SelectExpression> getSelectRows();

    String getWhereClause();
}
```

I have a class where I want to check whether two different implementations of this interface yields same results.

When I do :

Case 1 : `if (query1.equals(query2))` I get some hashcode and they are not same.

Case 2 : `if (query1.getSelectRows().equals(query2.getSelectRows()))` They are same.

Case 3 : `if (query1.getWhereClause().equals(query2.getWhereClause()))` They are same.

**Is there anyway to check whether query1 & query2 are same without changing the interface?** I do not have the liberty to modify the interface code. [I read about overriding in-built methods]

Comment: Why exactly doesn't `query1.equals(query2)` work?

Comment: query1 is 'xyz$1@2526' and query 2 is 'abc@2531'

Comment: That has got nothing to do with the `equals` method. That looks like the output from the default `toString` implementation. The implementations of `Query` should implement `equals` properly.

Comment: If you're comparing an object of class A with an object of class B, they're not equal, except for a very eccentric implementation of `equals()`.

Comment: Classes A&B do not have any objects. The implementation is slightly complicated. They only implement the methods in interface. I want to confirm the values returned from these classes are same.